# Why I get "Comparison method violates its general contract"

Tags: java, comparator

if I call this line of code

```
Arrays.sort(allNew, 0, sizeNew, mCatBPosComparator);
```

with that comparator

```
 private class BPosComparator implements Comparator<CatBPos> {

    private static final int SWAP_BPosS = 1;

    @Override
    public int compare(CatBPos p1, CatBPos p2) {
      int lCompare;

      if (TimeUtils.isNotVoid(p1.getHdopBPos().getTime()) && TimeUtils.isNotVoid(p2.getHdopBPos().getTime())) {
        lCompare = p1.getHdopBPos().getTime().compareTo(p2.getHdopBPos().getTime());
        if (lCompare != 0) {
          return lCompare;
        }
      }

      lCompare = p1.getBPos().getTime().compareTo(p2.getBPos().getTime());
      if (lCompare != 0) {
        return lCompare;
      }

      if (p1.getBPos().isDeparture() && p2.getBPos().isVacation()) {
        return SWAP_BPOS;
      } else if (p1.getBPos().isVacation() && p2.getBPos().isArrival()) {
        return SWAP_BPOS;
      }

      // Ankunft und Abfahrt für denselben Bahnhof sollen in der richtigen Reihenfolge sein
      if (p1.getBPos().isDeparture() && p2.getBPos().isArrival() && p1.getBPos().getStat().equals(p2.getBPos().getStat())) {
        return SWAP_BPOS;
      }

      return 0;
    }
  }
```

I runs into that Exception:

```
Comparison method violates its general contract!
```

I see a lot of topics regarding this. But I dont understand it.
Could you help me?

Comment: This exception usually means that three objects A, B, and C exist such that A>B, B>C, and A <= C. The "return 0" at the bottom is highly suspicious, though, because it reports items as equal when a set of elaborated criteria is not met.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I suspect this is at least one immediate problem:

```
if (p1.getBPos().isDeparture() && p2.getBPos().isVacation()) {
    return SWAP_BPOS;
} else if (p1.getBPos().isVacation() && p2.getBPos().isDeparture()) {
    return SWAP_BPOS;
}
```

If you call `compare(p1, p2)` and then `compare(p2, p1)` you'll get the same non-zero result... which breaks the comparison rules.

Basically, your comparison needs to obey the [documented rules](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Comparator.html#compare-T-T-). The above is *one* problem - it's entirely possible there are more. You should read the rules *very carefully* and think about how your comparison needs to work.

You can start off by negating `SWAP_BPOS` for the reverse situation:

```
if (p1.getBPos().isDeparture() && p2.getBPos().isVacation()) {
    return SWAP_BPOS;
} else if (p1.getBPos().isVacation() && p2.getBPos().isDeparture()) {
    return -SWAP_BPOS;
}
```

That may not be *everything* required, but it's a start.

Comment: Dear Jon. I did an copy&paste error by creating this question. please see my edited code. I think with the updated code the above part should be no problem.

Comment: @StefanBeike: Well it's still not clear that that's symmetric. It doesn't help that we don't know what the various properties mean - can something has `isDeparture` true *and* `isVacation` true, for example?

Comment: for some reason the first section leads to that problem. Basicaly I dont know why but thx a lot for your help.

Comment: @JonSkeet Please multiply your reputation in this April fools event!! The world need to see it!! HAHA

Answer (score 1):

You need to make sure your comparison operator obeys all the appropriate mathematical rules:

1. If A < B and B < C then A < C.
2. If A < B then B > A.
3. If A == B then B == A.

In particular, look out for code that may be returning the same ordering / result for opposite inputs. Your comparison needs to be able to definitively order your items.

In my experience, mistakes in point 2 seem to be the most common mistake.

Comment: 1) transitive, and 2,3) simetric, and reflexive you forgot xD

Comment: @nachokk Reflexive equality is implied by 2 (if arguments are identical but result is "not equal" then 2 must be violated when arguments are swapped). See also [`Comparator.compareTo`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Comparator.html#compare-T-T-), which parallels these rules.

Answer (score 0):

A comparison operator needs to be transitive. In short this means that you should define it in such a manner that if `a.compareTo(b)` is negative and `b.compareTo(c)` is negative, then `a.compareTo(c)` is also negative. This is somewhat intuitive - if a is less than b and b is less than c then a is less than c, too. Also you should make sure that if `a.compareTo(b)` is zero, than `b.compareTo(a)` is zero, i.e. if a equals b then b equals a.

Comment: Your second point and one missing point can be combined and generalized as `sign(a.compareTo(b)) = -sign(b.compareTo(a))` - remember, `a.compareTo(b)` must give the opposite ordering of `b.compareTo(a)` if `a!=b`; this is one of the most common implementation mistakes.

Comment: Yes but I tried to be more verbose to be more clear.

Answer (score 0):

Basically, your compare method needs to be consistent. If A > B, and B > C, then A must be greater than C. Your code is probably failing there.

Comment: If `A > B` and `B > C`, the assumption would be that `A > C`, and not the opposite.